# Laptop display twisting

Tags: laptop, laptop-display

Recently I've noticed this on 2 laptops that I own: The hinges on the lcd pivot are quite stiff; so when opening the display from the corner extremities, that corner of the screen twists backwards before the hinge assembly starts to give way and rotate. Is this in any way bad for the lcd? Or are lcds flexible to a certain degree?

Answer (score 0):

It's not good for the panel per se, but you probably won't see any detrimental effect for tens of thousands of operations under "normal" conditions; the materials all have a certain amount of give.